# Generating function of infinitesimal translation - classical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I am reading Sakurai's Modern quantum mechanics and at some point it's trying to draw a parallel between classical and quantum mechanics.

It says

> An infinitesimal translation in classical mechanics can be regarded as
>   a canonical transformation,  $$ \mathbf{x}_{\mathrm{new}} \equiv \mathbf{X}
>  = \mathbf{x} + d\mathbf{x}, \quad  \mathbf{p}_{\mathrm{new}} \equiv  \mathbf{P} = \mathbf{p}, \tag{1.6.28} $$ 
>   obtainable from the generating function $$ F_2(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{P}) = \mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{P} +
>  \mathbf{p}\cdot d\mathbf{x}.  \tag{1.6.29} $$

From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_(physics)) it seems that a generating function is something that one can differentiate to obtain the equation of motion of the system.

I mean I assume I need to differentiate $F$ with respect to $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{P}$? What equation of motion am I supposed to get from here?

Comment: You just read the instructions to differentiate w.r.t.  the arguments, so **x** and **P** to get **p** and **X**, the canonical tfmation displayed.

Comment: Where do I even get $F$ from? I can see that somehow I need to have $\mathbf{X} \cdot$ something ?

Comment: If it were not trivial to guess, a basic analytical mechanics book describes the methods.... Did you read up on [ct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation)s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. The infinitesimal change in position $d{\bf x}=\varepsilon~ {\bf f}({\bf x})$ can be thought of as an infinitesimal parameter $\varepsilon$ times a vector-valued function of the old position ${\bf x}$.
2. A [type-2 generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) $F_2({\bf x},{\bf P},t)$ for a canonical transformation depends on the old position ${\bf x}$, the new momentum ${\bf P}$, and possibly time $t$.
3. If the above does not make sense, then you should study Hamiltonian mechanics and canonical transformations, as Cosmas Zachos suggests in above comment, e.g. Ref. 1.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Section 9.

Comment: Is there a reason you changed $\mathrm{d}{\bf x}$ to $d{\bf x}$?

Comment: Yes. $d{\bf x}$ is the notation used by Sakurai. Personally I would prefer $\delta{\bf x}$ for an infinitesimal change. $\mathrm{d}{\bf x}$ looks like a one-form.